# Can't remove Firefox user preference for disallowing JavaScript alerts

Tags: firefox, javascript

For some Selinium test work, I need to keep JavaScript enabled in Firefox... yet specifically disable JavaScript's ability to launch alert boxes (Selenium doesn't yet handle them in the "onload" event).  After some searching online, I found that you can do this by setting the following user preference:

```
user_pref("capability.policy.default.Window.alert", "noAccess");
```

You can put this in the `user.js` for a particular Firefox profile, but I don't use multiple profiles.  So I added it by:

1. putting "`about:config`" in my address bar
2. right-clicking and selecting "new"
3. adding the name-value pair above

This works!  Firefox no longer supports JavaScript alert boxes.  However, now that I am through testing... the issue is that I cannot UNDO this.

When I go back to "`about:config`", I do not find that name-value pair in the list of preferences.  I likewise find nothing in "`prefs.js`".  Where did that preference get saved?  How I nuke it, and return to normal?

Comment: If you have more than one profile, have you browsed all the prefs.js in each profile? I would also make sure Firefox isn't running at this time.

Comment: I recall some versions of Firefox having a bug where newly-created prefs would not appear in `about:config` until Firefox was restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a moron.  It turns out that I was looking at the "prefs.js" in the Firefox installation directory.  I should have been looking at the "prefs.js" file under my home directory (the exact location may differ based on your operating system).  Changes made through "`about:config`" are persisted in the latter location.